# Who comprise this duo?

Tags: riddle, cryptic-clues

One the voice of a city in italy, the other a taker of fleece.
Together they make a duo.
Like calcium to cobalt.
Who rarely appear outside of their element.

Who are we?

**Hints***

> 1. We have been on the small _____ for decades.
>  2. We come from the VII.
>  3. We are siblings.

Comment: The taker of fleece could be a sheperd

Comment: @KateGregory whoops I think that was an accident, thanks for pointing that out, I'll remove it.

Comment: I can't help but feel this is something to do with movies and/or actors.

Comment: @jhabbott you're on the right track

Comment: @Daedric I have quite a few ideas, but I can't figure out how they fit all of the clues, only one or two.

Comment: this is going to be miles off - Marty Friedman (Martini is Italian) and Jason Becker from Caco-phony https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacophony_(band)?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Another interesting answer but not the one im after sorry

Comment: Calcium to Cobalt could mean a shift of A to O, (Ca -> Co)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was a collaborative effort between myself and [question_asker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17250/question-asker). I figured out:

> *taker of fleece* could be **shearer**;
>  and that *voice of* and *rarely appear* hints at a voice actor

This was confirmed by the OP with some further hints and then [question_asker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17250/question-asker) figured out the rest...

**COLLABO-POWERS ACTIVATE**

> You said *voice actor* and *Shearer* and my thoughts went to Harry Shearer and Dan [Castellaneta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castellaneta), both voice actors on The Simpsons ("on the small *screen* for decades", maybe?). They are Kang and Kodos (Ca and Co), the dome-headed squidlike alien things.

Comment: I associate 'cobalt' with blue, not black

Comment: If I have an idea, would you like me to edit your answer?

Comment: hah you're right it's blue - I must have biased my thinking at the time to fit! Re. editing... yeah you could try it - I don't know how 'discussion' really works in this format as per my meta question.

Comment: anyway, I edited it - whether or not my edit is even on the right track, I think this is a perfect example of a situation where both a sanctioned collaborative tool as well as a method of backchannel communication would be useful.

Comment: Ooh good thoughts - collabo powers activate indeed :D

Comment: @jhabbott you are correct, well done, it is Simpson characters, my calcium and cobalt hints are kind of stupid but its about the sounds of the names. And a specific theme is their element... just polish your answer off and ill mark it correct. :D collabo powers!

Comment: @jhabbott Since it's your answer, I'll let you clean it up for the checkmark if you'd like?

Comment: @question_asker im confused did you come up with the simpson idea or jhabbott?

Comment: @jhabbott um just incase it looks like i said the answer was simpson characters, its actually a specific duo. My bad.

Comment: @question_asker after reviewing the edit it appears you  are the one with the simpson idea, anyway its not yet answered so you could post your own answer, if you have figured it out

Comment: @daedric at this point I feel like it would be rude to post my own answer. I'll make an edit here if it's all the same to you

Comment: @question_asker well its up to you but the question hasnt been answered, and I didnt realize you had added that information.

Comment: @Daedric so just so I'm not barking up the wrong tree: are the voice actors correct, or did I just stumble on a massive coincidence?

Comment: @question_asker the voice actors are correct, its two characters from the simpsons, I suggest you figure it out before someone else does. Also I posted a new hint.

Comment: @daedric OK done

Comment: @question_asker a true gentleman, congrats and correct.

Comment: Good job @question_asker - didn't feel right taking the credit for this so I edited in a clarification of the collab.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit off the mark, as it isn't necessarily a duo, but you could be:

> Jason and the Argonauts.

One the voice of a city in italy, the other a taker of fleece.

> The taker of fleece that I am thinking of is Jason, who quested for the Golden Fleece with his team of Argonauts.  In Italy, there is a municipality called San Paolo d'Argon.

Together they make a duo.

> Again, not the most straightforward duo, but this *is* a cryptic puzzle, so nobody is saying it should be straightforward.  Anyway, one and another are a duo; in this case, Jason is one and the Argonauts are another.

Like calcium to cobalt.
Who rarely appear outside of their element.

> This seems to point to the element Argon on the periodic table, but there is likely more than I am acknowledging.

But again, this duo may in fact be

> Jason and the Argonauts

Comment: Interesting idea but unfortunately not what I'm looking for.

Comment: For what it's worth, I thought of Jason, too.

Comment: I like the Argon, as it is a noble gas, which rarely appears outside it's elemental form.  But Krypton could be a better choice, as it's in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

**The Voice**

> A common Cryptic keyword indicating "Sounds Like" or  homonym.  This would apply to "city in italy" and possibly, but not necessarily the "taker of fleece"  Livorno and shearer --> Laverne and Shirley?  But I can't parse the rest.